# Aligning an EditText with a Button

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to horizontally align an EditText with a Button without success.  Both should be of the same height and their tops and bottoms should align with each other.  Here's my code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/quantity"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/quantity_label"
        android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background" />
    <Button
        android:onClick="submitButtonTapped"
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/quantity"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/submit_icon"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:text="@string/submit" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The result is that the bottom of the two elements are aligned.  The focus border of the EditText extends below the Button.  The EditText does not extend to the height of the Button, even with the focus border.  How do I get them aligned?

Comment: The problem in android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background" - without it works as expected

Comment: Without that line the problem is reversed: the tops are aligned and the bottom of the EditText doesn't reach the bottom of the Button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set in dimen/line_height value.
2. Use this layout

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
> android:layout_width="fill_parent"
> android:layout_height="@dimen/line_height"
> android:orientation="horizontal" >
> <EditText
>     android:id="@+id/quantity"
>     android:inputType="number"
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_width="100dp"
>     android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background" />
>
> <Button
>     android:id="@+id/submit"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     android:drawableLeft="@drawable/submit_icon"
>     android:onClick="submitButtonTapped"
>     android:text="@string/submit" />
>  </LinearLayout>
> ```

Comment: The @dimen/line_height code produces an error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_height' with value '@dimen/
 line_height'). Thanks.

Comment: create file res/values/dimens.xml: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <dimen name="line_height">50dip</dimen>
</resources>'

Comment: It's hardcoding, which I really want to avoid, but I'll accept this answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

just add margin to button

like this

```
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
```

also use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout and also use

```
andorid:layout_alignTop = "@id/quantity"
```

hope this will work..